# Numpy Python: How to change 2d array elements based on condition?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy 2D array representing some x,y coordinates.
Given a reference point [a,b] and a distance 'c', I want to replace the elements in my 2D array, such that all points whose distance from [a,b]>c are set to [0,0] and those with a distance smaller than c are set to [1,1]. I tried to use where() in many variations, but did not succeed.

Example Input:

```
arr2D = np.array([[10,20],[30,40],[50,60]])
refPoint = np.array([29,41])
c = 5
```

Output should be: `[[0,0],[1,1],[0,0]]`

Any help is appreciated...

Comment: Show your code please. [ask]

Answer (score 0):

```
np.array([[int(np.linalg.norm(a - refPoint, 2) < c)]*len(refPoint) for a in arr2D])
```

This gives exactly the format you are looking for, the "*len(refPoint)" seems a bit redundant though.

Comment: That works! Many thanks. I just wonder about speed. It basically uses a python list comprehension to iterate over the array elements, which is not very fast. That's the reason I tried variations of np.where(), so to only use pure number.